# Maintain instances through application without singleton

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have researched a lot, and found a few different options and opinions, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm working on a project where there are *almost-non-variable* classes (e.g. Users) and *very-variable classes* (e.g. Meetings). I have a repository for each class which gets data directly from database, but I would like to implement a service layer for almost-non-variable classes. This way I could only load them at application's startup.

**What can I do to load Users at startup and maintain it on RAM?** So I don't have to fetch database every time I need a specific User.

Is singleton pattern a good option? I'm avoiding it, because of people saying it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for [SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: "people are saying it's an anti-pattern". IMO no, it just needs to be used where appropriate. You could potentially use it here. But what are the consequences if the user loads the app and then doesn't close it for days or weeks? Plenty of people leave their machines running without switching them off. What would happen if the data became stale? ....

Comment: .... Consider whether reloading this data from the database is really such a problem...are you actually experiencing performance issues currently? Don't make compromises in your code if you haven't got an actual problem, or any evidence to suggest that in a production environment (i.e. at production scale) you would start to experience one. Just something simple like fetching some user data from the DB when a form is loaded is quite unlikely to do that, unless your DB is not set up very well or your network bandwidth is very poor....and both probably have their own solutions outside the app

Comment: Thanks @Ian I didn't know that site.

Comment: We're all here to learn ;)

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I had think about this. My guess was to find a way to refresh the data.

I think you're right and I'm overthinking it. It was wrong for me to get from the database the same data a lot of times but at the moment I haven't performance issues doing it.

Comment: Well you could refresh it at regular intervals. But TBH you might as well refresh it whenever it's actually needed, like the rest of your data. Then there's no doubt or problems with stale data. This is much more user-friendly. With modern infrastructure you'll be unlikely to encounter any problems doing this, unless the "almost-non-variable" data it needs to fetch is huge (like 10s of Megabytes every time or something) - but that sounds unlikely, from your description.

Comment: Sorry @ADyson, I edited my last comment. You're right, the size of my "almost-non-variable" data is not as big. I will fetch it from the database. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SergiDomènech singleton is fine for a factory, especially if you need to maintain state (as opposed to a static class). Your factory singleton can load the users at startup and keep them in a list in memory, then return instances when requested. You could also consider Lazy loading if you only need one user active at a time (i.e. you don't necessarily need to load all users). A lot of options, but this is a pretty broad question. Good luck

Comment: Thank you @djv, I will check the Lazy Loading concept in .NET :)

Comment: @Ian when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)